# How to increase font size of timestamps in notifications using Notifee in Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, expo

I'm currently developing an app using Expo, and I'm using the Notifee module to manage push notifications. Notifee has been great for handling notifications and even allows me to include timers directly within the Android notifications using the timestamp field.

However, I've run into an issue with the font size of these timestamps, particularly on certain devices where the font appears to be too small. I'd like to make the timestamp font larger so it's more readable for users. Is there a way to achieve this using the Notifee module? If not, are there any alternative solutions to address this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Additional Context:

I'm using Expo to develop my app.
I'm managing push notifications using the Notifee module.
I've successfully integrated timers within notifications using the timestamp field.
The issue is that the font size of timestamps within the notifications is too small on some Android devices.
I'm looking for a way to increase the font size of these timestamps or alternative solutions to address the readability concern.